# Updating data on external Excel workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

Since many days I am now struggling with following situation:

*I have an Excel WB, a summary view of various other WB's with data in them. Let's call thissummary view WB as COCKPIT.XLSM
As stated, there are many other WB that have certain calculations in them. Let's call them INPUT1.XLSM, INPUT2.XLSM, ...*

I want to run a macro in COCKPIT, and this macro will do for each and every INPUT file basically following:

- Open INPUTn file
- Update data in INPUTn file (these updates are calculations done by a common foreign exchange file)
- Save INTPUTn file
- Proceed to next (INPUTn+1)

If I manually open any one of the INPUT files, the data is automatically updated (all data are refreshed upon file open), so this all works fine. 
But if I do this remotely from the macro running on COCKPIT, the updates in the INPUT files are not performed. Almost as if the INPUT file is opened but in a frozen state, i.e. no update of data.

Question: how do I tell the macro running on COCKPIT that it should perform actions on the INPUT files (i.e. let its data update, and save the result again)?

Thanks for the great help I am hoping for. Probably just a small issue, but as you guys can tell by now, I am a novice in VBA

Martin

Comment: You need to change the second parameter in row 16 of your code.

Comment: Please update your question with the macro in COCKPIT.xlsm.